# Create IE addon using VC++ 2010 express edition

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, sdk, atl, add-on

I need to create an addon for IE using VC++ 2010 express edition. It requires to work on BHO and create dll files. So can any one please provide me the steps to follow and references. Also I came to know that it requires sdk and wtl/atl so please help me regarding the same.

I have downloaded and installed VC++ 2010 express edition but I am  not able to move forward.
Please help me.

Comment: ATL is not required but it's a lot better than writing from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

ATL is not available in VC Express. Check [Writing a BHO in Plain C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/BHOinCPP.aspx) for an example based on Windows SDK.

Suggested reading:

- Essential COM by Don Box
- Programming Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 by Scott Roberts